# How do I keep my COUNTIF function from counting my column header?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, countif

I have a column filled with dates and am trying to count all the cells after a certain date, using COUNTIF(A:A,">"&DATE(xx,xx,xx)). The problem is it keeps including my column header ("Date") in its count. Why is this happening, and how can I fix it?

I think part of the problem may be that I'm using a cell reference for the date, so my actual formula is COUNTIF(A:A,">"&B1), where B1 contains a date in Excel format ("DATE(xx,xx,xx)"). I checked and I don't have this issue when I simply put a date into my original formula.

I have no clue what's going on and any help would be appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: Just deduct 1 from the count?

Comment: Could you provide your sample Table? I tested with simple Date column with "Date" header, the formula works fine. Please provide more information.

Answer (score -1):

COUNTIF only accept column ranges, you'll need to use `INDIRECT` to search in specific ranges.

`=COUNTIF(INDIRECT("A2:A99"),">"&B2)`

Notice how INDIRECT needs an explicit starting & ending row numbers.

Comment: This statement is simply false. Sorry for the downvote. I'd rather not. Maybe you can rectify?

Comment: @JvdV Which part is false?

Comment: And your suggestion to subtract 1 assumes the comparison returns true, adding 1 to the total, but that's not guaranteed in other use cases.

Comment: `=COUNTIF(A2:A99,">"&B2)` is a perfect syntax. There is absolutely no need to use `INDIRECT()` and even make this volatile. It's just .....incorrect. Sorry, but that's what it is.

Comment: I'll test it again, it didn't work for me on Excell Online.